# Cython: recompile modules

Tags: cython, cythonize

I have one quick and very basic question about compiling modules in Cython: I have compiled a couple of modules using distutils and the command "build_ext --inplace". When I make a change to one of these modules, repeating "build_ext --inplace" leads to an error:

fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users...\PycharmProjects...pyd'

When I close PyCharm and restart it, everything works fine - it seems like the current files cannot be deleted because they're still in use unless I restart everything. Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the restart and losing all the objects in memory?

Best,
T

Comment: Generally python c extensions can't be unloaded, you will need to restart your python interpreter. I'm not a pycharm user, but presumably there is some way to restart the interpreter without restarting the whole IDE?

Comment: That is probably Windows specific (exclusive file locks). It works fine on Linux with `reload(extension_module)`.